# Sudo execute shell script is different behavior compared to direct user execute it

Tags: shell, sudo

My customer has a script `runDaemon.ksh` that must be executed as user `app-admin`. The script will create socket connection to an IP with port 3001.

I was asked to automate this script but using other user `automation`. They already give my user privilege to sudo and execute `runDaemon.ksh` as `app-admin` in their `/etc/sudoers`.

When I try to execute my script using `automation` with this command `sudo -u app-admin ./runDaemon.ksh`, the daemon started but it never create socket connection to target IP with port 3001. It very strange, I ask the customer to direct login, execute the script, and running normally.

How to make my user that granted `sudo` have a same behavior like the real user do?

Comment: How do you know the daemon started? Does `app-admin` have anything in their `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` that is needed?

Comment: using command `jps | grep Daemon`. My customer and me dunno whether `app-admin` need it or not, because the application is developed by other vendor a very long time ago.

Comment: Can you get your customer to directly login and run `env -i PATH=/bin:/usr/bin HOME=$HOME USER=$USER LOGNAME=$LOGNAME ./runDaemon.ksh` and see if the daemon works correctly? If it doesn't then there is a good chance that something is being set up in the profile.

Comment: hi @icarus thanks for your suggestion.. i'm afraid he won't try this because this is production server. If there is something being set in the profile, can i execute the command from automation with the same profile that app-admin set? Can i use `sudo -u -i` to simulate it ?

Comment: `sudo -i -u app-admin ./runDaemon.ksh` would be a good thing to try. It will not be exactly the same, but it might be good enough.

Comment: ok i will try it.. hope it works

Comment: hi @icarus, i already try `sudo -i -u app-admin ./runDaemon.ksh` but it ask password even sysadmin already specified NOPASSWD in etc sudoers

`(automation) NOPASSWD: /runDaemon.ksh`

how to by pass password in /etc/sudoers?

Comment: We stand a risk of getting sidetracked! Can you get the full path to runDaemon.ksh put into the sudoers file?

Comment: @icarus, thanks your kindly reminder. for this question, `sudo -i -u` solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-i` parameter in sudo allows to run script with same behavior like real user execute it.

`sudo -i -u app-admin ./runDaemon.ksh`